# What is the location of output of thrust::reduce operation(GPU RAM or CPU RAM)?

Tags: cuda, reduce, ram, thrust

When we use thrust::reduce in the following example, the output is an int. Is this output (**sum** variable in code) located on the GPU or CPU RAM?

If it is in CPU RAM, how to access/retain the variable in the gpu?
The reduce operation happens on the device(GPU) so at some point the output should be in the GPU.

```
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

int main()
{
thrust::device_vector<int> D(6);
D[0]=0;
D[1]=1;
D[2]=2;
D[3]=3;
D[4]=4;
D[5]=5;
int sum = thrust::reduce(thrust::device,D.begin(), D.end(), (int) 0, thrust::plus<int>());

}
```

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786163/1231073) by Robert Crovella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result `sum` is on the CPU, you can refer to this [documentation](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide#reductions).

The result was probably at some point on the GPU, if the final result was computed on it. I didn't checked the implementation, but it could be possible that the final result is computed on the CPU. If you need to access it on the GPU, just pass it as a kernel argument, or [copy](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc263dbe6574220cc776b45438fc351e8) it into global memory.